# How to create a ResourcePool of agents that are instances of an agent type already existing in one of AnyLogic Libraries?

Tags: anylogic

How to create a ResourcePool of agents that are instances of an agent type already existing in one of AnyLogic Libraries (for example the Conveyor agent type of the process modeling library)

I tried to do split then Conveyor and service and i combined after but it is not accurate representation of the real life and it creates lots of errors.

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do, but you clearly didn't understand my last answer to you

Comment: unfortunately your answer is not practical in my case, as i have many conveyors, so the basic concept of failure token for each conveyor would require a source and sink for each conveyor is complicated and not practical and will not be attached to a resource pool, so i till be hard to present it in a dashboard .

Comment: false, you need only 1 source and 1 sink...

Comment: yes for each conveyor, and i said that i have around 15 conveyors and that is the problem...

Comment: false, you need 1 source for ALL conveyors... the token that is generated in the source has the conveyor information as a variable

Comment: what can i do to simulate each breakdown for each conveyor, knowing that there is a different rate of breakdowns for each conveyor?